# Array included in array search with elasticsearch

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, lucene

I have users indexed with categories as follows

```
{
 id: 1
 name: John
 categories: [
   {
    id: 1
    name: Category 1
   },
   {
    id: 2
    name: Category 2
   }
 ]
},
{
 id: 2
 name: Mark
 categories: [
   {
    id: 1
    name: Category 1
   }
 ]
}
```

And I'm trying to get all the documents with Category 1 or Category 2 with

```
{
 filter:
   {
     bool: {
       must: [
         {
           terms: {user.categories.id: [1, 2]}
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

But It only returns the first document that has the two categories, what I am doing wrong?
As I understood, terms search that one of the values is contained in the field, so for user 1
user.categories.id: [1, 2]
user 2
user.categories.id: [1]
Categoy id 1 is contained in both documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this is probably with a [nested filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-filter.html). You'll have to specify the `"nested"` type in your mapping, though.

I can set up an index like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "categories": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "id": {
                     "type": "long"
                  },
                  "name": {
                     "type": "string"
                  }
               }
            },
            "id": {
               "type": "long"
            },
            "name": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

then add some docs:

```
PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "John",
   "categories": [
      { "id": 1, "name": "Category 1" },
      { "id": 2, "name": "Category 2" }
   ]
}

PUT /test_index/doc/2
{
   "id": 2,
   "name": "Mark",
   "categories": [
      { "id": 1, "name": "Category 1" }
   ]
}

PUT /test_index/doc/3
{
   "id": 3,
   "name": "Bill",
   "categories": [
      { "id": 3, "name": "Category 3" },
      { "id": 4, "name": "Category 4" }
   ]
}
```

Now I can use a nested terms filter like this:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "constant_score": {
         "filter": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "categories",
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                   "categories.id": [1, 2]
                }
            }
         }
         },
         "boost": 1.2
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": 1,
               "name": "John",
               "categories": [
                  {
                     "id": 1,
                     "name": "Category 1"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": 2,
                     "name": "Category 2"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": 2,
               "name": "Mark",
               "categories": [
                  {
                     "id": 1,
                     "name": "Category 1"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/668aefe910643b52a3a10d40aca67104491668fc